# How to return a JSON tree format from SQL query?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I currently have a table that contains a **content_id**, **root_id**, **parent_id** and **content_level**. This table is self-referencing, in which a record could have related child records. The parent records do not know about the child records but the child record know about the parents via the **parent_id** field.

This is the query used for fetching all the records with the root content at the top. The root content has content_level = 0, and both root_id and parent_id = NULL. For the rest of the records, the root_id field will match the content_id of root record.

```
SELECT *
FROM jccontent c2 
WHERE c2.content_id = 138412032
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT j.*
    FROM jccontent AS c 
    INNER JOIN jccontent j on c.content_id = j.parent_id 
    WHERE j.root_id  = 138412032 
)
ORDER BY content_level ;
```

From here, I would like to build a JSON tree structure where it will contain the root as the top element, and then nested children elements that follows. I would like to complete this portion using purely SQL. Currently I have done it in code and it works well, but would like to see if doing it in SQL will be better.

My desired output would be something like this:

```
{
  "content_id": 138412032,
  "root_id": null,
  "parent_id": null,
  "content_level": 0,
  "children": [
    {
      "content_id": 1572864000,
      "root_id": 138412032,
      "parent_id": 138412032,
      "content_level": 1,
      "children": [
        {
          "content_id": 1606418432,
          "root_id": 138412032,
          "parent_id": 1572864000,
          "content_level": 2,
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "content_id": 515899393,
          "root_id": 138412032,
          "parent_id": 1572864000,
          "content_level": 2,
          "children": [
            {
              "content_id": 75497471,
              "root_id": 138412032,
              "parent_id": 515899393,
              "content_level": 3,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "content_id": 1795162113,
      "root_id": 138412032,
      "parent_id": 138412032,
      "content_level": 1,
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

If there is any additional information required, please let me know. I will be glad to share. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
WITH recursive cte AS (
    SELECT content_id, parent_id, content_level 
    FROM jccontent 
    WHERE content_id = 138412032
    UNION ALL
    SELECT j.content_id, j.parent_id, j.content_level
    FROM jccontent j
    INNER JOIN cte c ON j.parent_id = c.content_id
)
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id' VALUE cte.content_id, 'parent_id' VALUE cte.parent_id, 'level' VALUE cte.content_level) 
FROM cte 
ORDER BY cte.content_level;
```

Comment: Hi, I would like it to be nested into one JSON tree object, where the root element is at the very top. But thank you.

Comment: I don't think this can be done in SQL